# Is this the correct way to process results through the Spring Integration Flow?

Tags: kotlin, spring-integration, reactive

I am currently working on a personal project - in which I need my Spring application to take queries from an EMQX (MQTT Server) and query its data for corresponding results, and then push the results to a topic with the query UUID.

This is working - after many hours understanding how the Spring Integration framework works.  But I think the way in which the handler is using "block" is incorrect - and not in keeping with the manner in which the Integration Flow should operate.   Whilst this works I do want to make sure it is being done properly - out of respect for the work - and to avoid future issues.

The code snippet below should be enough to understand what it is that I'm trying to achieve - and where the potential issue lies.

```
    @Bean
fun mqttInFlow() : Publisher<Message<String>> {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(inbound())
        .handle<String> { payload, headers ->
            val emotionalOutput: EmotionalOutput = gson.fromJson(payload, EmotionalOutput::class.java)
            emotionalPrintService.populateEmotionalOutput(emotionalOutput).map {
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(gson.toJson(it))
                    .copyHeaders(headers)
                    .setHeader(MqttHeaders.TOPIC, "query/" + it.query_uuid).build()
            }.block()
        }
        .channel(outgoingChannel())
        .toReactivePublisher()
}
```

EDIT - Thanks for the advice - here is what I understood to be the potential edit for the Kotlin DSL solution - this is now producing an error - complaining that an output-channel or replyChannel was not available - nothing outside of the this function has been changed.

```
    @Bean
fun newMqttInFlow() =
    integrationFlow (inbound()) {
       wireTap {
            handle<String> { payload, headers ->
                gson.fromJson<EmotionalOutput>(payload, EmotionalOutput::class.java).let { emotionalOutput ->
                    emotionalPrintService.populateEmotionalOutput(emotionalOutput).map { populatedEmotionalOutput ->
                        MessageBuilder.withPayload(gson.toJson(populatedEmotionalOutput))
                            .copyHeaders(headers)
                            .setHeader(MqttHeaders.TOPIC, populatedEmotionalOutput.query_uuid)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        channel("outgoingChannel")
    }
```

Exception is :

exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Although I have many years experience with Java - this approach is new - so thank you very much for your assistance.  It's appreciated.  If the whole class would be useful - I can post that.

**EDIT**

Here is the Configuration file - which might give a better insight into what might be causing this secondary error -

> 021-03-28 21:59:48.008 ERROR 84492 --- [T Call: divnrin] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'mqttOutbound'; defined in: 'class path resource [io/divnr/appserver/configuration/MQTTConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@4a9419d7']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This default converter can only handle 'byte[]' or 'String' payloads; consider adding a transformer to your flow definition, or provide a BytesMessageMapper, or subclass this converter for reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable payloads, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=MonoMapFuseable, headers={mqtt_receivedRetained=false, mqtt_id=0, mqtt_duplicate=false, id=c5a75283-c0fe-ebac-4168-dabddd989da9, mqtt_receivedTopic=source/d9e50e8f-67e0-4505-7ca2-4d05b1242207, mqtt_receivedQos=0, timestamp=1616961588004}]
> at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
> at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
> at

The full class is provided here.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
class MQTTConfiguration(val emotionalPrintService: EmotionalPrintService,
                    val gson: Gson,
                    val applicationConfiguration: ApplicationConfiguration) {

@Bean
fun mqttServiceFactory() : MqttPahoClientFactory {
    return DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory().apply {
        connectionOptions = MqttConnectOptions().apply {
            serverURIs = arrayOf<String>(applicationConfiguration.mqttServerAddress)
        }
    }
}

@Bean
fun newMqttInFlow() =
    integrationFlow (inbound()) {
        handle<String> { payload, headers ->
            gson.fromJson<EmotionalOutput>(payload, EmotionalOutput::class.java).let { emotionalOutput ->
                emotionalPrintService.populateEmotionalOutput(emotionalOutput).map { populatedEmotionalOutput ->
                    MessageBuilder.withPayload(gson.toJson(populatedEmotionalOutput))
                        .copyHeaders(headers)
                        .setHeader(MqttHeaders.TOPIC, populatedEmotionalOutput.query_uuid).build()
                }
            }
        }
        channel(outgoingChannel())
    }

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(requiresReply = "false", inputChannel = "outgoingChannel")
fun mqttOutbound(): MessageHandler {
    val messageHandler = MqttPahoMessageHandler("divnrout", mqttServiceFactory())
    messageHandler.setAsync(true)
    return messageHandler
}

@Bean
fun outgoingChannel() : FluxMessageChannel {
    return FluxMessageChannel()
}

@Bean
fun inbound(): MessageProducerSupport {
    return MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("divnrin", mqttServiceFactory(),
        "source/" + applicationConfiguration.sourceUuid).apply {
        setConverter(DefaultPahoMessageConverter())
        setQos(1)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed don't need that `block()` in the end of your `handle()`. You just can return the `Mono` from that `emotionalPrintService.populateEmotionalOutput()` and the framework will take for you about the proper subscription and back-pressure handling.

What you would need yet is to make that `outgoingChannel()` as a `FluxMessageChannel`.
See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#reactive-streams

Plus consider to move your `IntegrationFlow` solution to the proper Kotlin DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kotlin-dsl.html#kotlin-dsl

Also: when it is a `FluxMessageChannel` in the end of flow, there is no reason to worry about a `toReactivePublisher()` - the `FluxMessageChannel` is a `Publisher<Message<?>>` by itself.

**UPDATE**

The problem is here:

```
handle<String>( { payload, headers ->
        gson.fromJson<EmotionalOutput>(payload, EmotionalOutput::class.java).let { emotionalOutput ->
            emotionalPrintService.populateEmotionalOutput(emotionalOutput).map { populatedEmotionalOutput ->
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(gson.toJson(populatedEmotionalOutput))
                    .copyHeaders(headers)
                    .setHeader(MqttHeaders.TOPIC, populatedEmotionalOutput.query_uuid).build()
            }
        }
    }) { async(true) }
```

See that `async(true)` option. Unfortunately in the current version we don't let it to process reactive reply in the reactive manner by default. You have to say that you'd like to be an async at this end-point. So, your `Publisher` reply and  and `FluxMessageChannel` as an output is going to do the proper trick.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, Artem.   I have made the suggested corrections - however this is producing an error.   I have edited my question - so as to hopefully provide anyone finding this query with a full answer.   Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove that `wireTap` wrapping. Not sure why you have it at all - no one in the original code. Anyway: the `wireTap` is an interceptor for one-way sub-flow. It is really the fact that it cannot find where to go with a result of that handle.

Comment: Yes - that was a mistake - or rather misunderstanding.   Removed this - and now receive a "This default converter can only handle 'byte[]' or 'String' payloads; consider adding a transformer to your flow definition" - I'm imagining this is because of something I've misconfigured - and it's not sure what do with the Mono object?

Comment: That is something better to share as a stacktrace in the question , but anyway you need to be sure that `outgoingChannel` is a `FluxMessageChannel`

Comment: Yes - quite right - I have shared the details of both the new stack trace and code --- I suspect I am not seeing something - code fatigue...

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Magic - it works - thank you so much for your assistance Artem - you've saved me much time.   I will be sure to put my full solution in a blog post to help others.  Thanks again.